# ios - app crash when click on a button on a child view from nib

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hi I am developing an iOS app and come on a strange problem.
I have a main viewcontroller that have some buttons when clicked they will open another view that connected to nib file and that nib file contain a button to close it, the problem is whenever I click that button the app crash with no reason or log.

This how I open the nib file:

```
BrowserViewController *browservc = [[BrowserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"browser" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

browservc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,490,320,381);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{
                     browservc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 187, 320, 460);
                     [self.view addSubview:browservc.view];
                     [browservc.webView loadRequest:request];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

And this who I want to close it:

```
- (IBAction)closeWebView:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Closed!");
}
```

When the app crash I just receive this:

```
(lldb)
```

Thanks.

Comment: what crash message do you get?

Comment: disable breakpoints, or hit "play" button multiple times, application will crash and you will receive reason.

Comment: I have no breakpoints, it only crash when I click on the close button.

Comment: It show no message but (lldb) in the log

Comment: What is the nib of BrowserViewController (initWithNibName:@"browser") check the nib name is correct

Comment: It is correct for sure, the view is showing up correctly and all functions are okay, except the button press event.

Comment: Add [browservc didMoveToParentViewController:self] after [self.view addSubview:browservc.view] See if that works

Comment: If this crashes only when you select the button, then there must be something connected wrongly with the IBAction, is the UIButton subclassed at all? It's difficult to say from your description, though I recommend deleting the button, any properties connected and IBActions and then re-adding the button and action.

Comment: I tried to add a new fresh button with a new action, but no hope

Answer (score 0):

If the app runs in the simulator, try to reset the simulator and clean your build and run your app again.

Comment: I did, but the problem still exist.

Comment: Try to delete the :(id)Sender and reconnect the button to your button.

Comment: when I do i get this error    -[__NSMallocBlock__ closeWebView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f91ab80fe50